# Trying to get network error alert to show on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

Ok so I am trying to get this app to show network error alert codes. I have added the SystemConfiguration.framework framework and Apple's "Reachability" sample code.

Here is the viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Reachability;

@interface Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController : UIViewController {

    Reachability* internetReachable;
    Reachability* hostReachable;
}

@property BOOL internetActive;
@property BOOL hostActive;

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;

@end
```

And here is the viewcontroller.m file:

```
#import "Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h";

@implementation Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController

@synthesize internetActive;
@synthesize hostActive;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // check for internet connection
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

        internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];

        // check if a pathway to a random host exists
        hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];

        // now patiently wait for the notification
    }

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)

            {
            case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
            {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
        self.hostActive = YES;

        break;

    }
}
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}

@end
```

The app runs fine without any errors or warnings but it doesn't show an alert when there is no internet connection. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Please? I really need to get this to work.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show any alerts, it only logs some messages. Are the messages showing up in your run log?

Comment: Hi amorya, thanks for your help but I don't know how to access my run log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually displaying an alert anywhere. To do that, you'll do something similar to the following:

```
UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Unavailable" message:@"MESSAGE ABOUT INTERNET UNAVAILABLE HERE." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorView show];
[errorView release];
```

Also, it's important to note that viewDidLoad can be called an arbitrary number of times on a view controller after initialization. It's better to have any notification observers declared in the designated initializer instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, please can you advise me on how to do this?

Comment: You should at least be seeing the NSLog statements in the console of the running program. Are you? You can access the run log from Xcode by going to Run > Console.

Comment: I worked out how to access the run log/console thing and I think I am yeah.

Comment: [Session started at 2011-01-26 23:08:48 +0000.]
2011-01-26 23:08:50.792 App[2856:207] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2011-01-26 23:08:50.793 App[2856:207] The internet is working via WIFI.
2011-01-26 23:08:50.793 App[2856:207] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2011-01-26 23:08:50.793 App[2856:207] A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

Comment: Great. So all that is required is to create an actual alert view. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks very much - I put the code that you provided just underneath the last "break;". I think I am putting it in the wrong place because the app is working just as before.

Comment: NVM I got it to work by placing the code you provided just before the first break, but now I have another problem. If there is no internet upon opening the app the error works as intended, but if the app loses connection after the app has opened with an internet connection the error displays, but 4 times, which I think has something to do with that I have 4 UIWebViews?